# Is there a framework for writing a decentral application?

Tags: client-server, distributed, p2p, bittorrent, dht

If I want to write a node for a P2P application (like Bitcoin, Bitorrent, etc.) there are a lot of parts that are the same:

- I need to bootstrap to the network (discover other peers)
- I need to manage a list of peers, and monitor their states
- I need to retrieve lists of more peers from my neighbour peers
- Etc, etc.

Since I don't want to re-invent the wheel, is their a framework that I could as a sort of base library to build on?

Comment: are you looking for academic or practical purposes? I think some such libraries might exist, but real world applications seem roll their own due to different needs.

Comment: @the8472 practical purposes

Comment: I typically check [this out](https://github.com/kgryte/awesome-peer-to-peer) for any p2p libraries.. Also to bootstrap the network bitcoin officially uses [this repo](https://github.com/TheBlueMatt/dnsseed) . Not sure if it is still in use though.

Answer (score 0):

You mention both bitcoin and bittorrent, which are quite different, so I'm assuming you don't want to be bound to any specific protocol or even serialization format.

And yet you mention peer-discovery and stats-management which are high-level concerns, be built *on top* of some network protocol.
But the protocol dictates how such a mechanism would work.

It sortof sounds like you're asking if there are pre-built roofs that would fit on skyscrapers just as well as on a wood cabin.

So if you actually want to design your own protocol you probably should look more at the foundation first.

- which language do you want to use
- what IO / event processing libraries are available
- what protocol parsers and serializers are available
- do you aim for throughput? low memory footprint? low latency? minimal amount of programmer-hours spent?
- what kind of security is needed? heavy crypto use at the protocol level will need a trustworthy crypto library (don't roll your own!)
- what kind of auxiliary things do you need (where does the data go? filesystem? databases? do you need a UI?)

Alternatively, depending how one interprets your question, if you want to write a client for a *specific network* then you should simply look for a library implementing the core concepts of that specific network while freeing you up to implement the rest of the application.
In bittorrent's case such an example would be [libtorrent](http://www.libtorrent.org/)

Comment: Bitcoin and Bittorrent operate exactly the same? Just the protocol is different. But i want to write the protocol myself. Prefer C. And all the other stuff like GUI and DB and platform dont matter, because its just a networking library?

Comment: C? I have little experience with that, but I doubt you'll find a library at the abstraction level that you asked for in your question. Also, to me bitcoin and bittorrent look different on many conceptual levels.

Comment: I think you dont really understand the question, and I may have formulated it a bit too vague. But Ive committed code for both projects, and all the stuff until the actual handshake is pretty similar.

Comment: That strikes me as fairly generic networking / message (de-)serialization stuff with some crypto thrown in. not really p2p-specific.